# Can't get NLog to work

Tags: nlog

I am having no luck getting NLog to work.  Working through the [tutorial](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Tutorial), I have the exact code as seen there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NLog;

namespace NLog2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new MyClass();
            c.MyMethod1();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void MyMethod1()
        {
            logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
            logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
            logger.Info("Sample informational message");
            logger.Warn("Sample warning message");
            logger.Error("Sample error message");
            logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");

            // alternatively you can call the Log() method 
            // and pass log level as the parameter.
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Sample fatal error message");
        }
    }
}
```

My config file (named NLog.config) looks like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets>
        <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="file.txt" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I get no output.  Can someone see what the issue is here?

Comment: Set `throwExceptions="true"` and `internalLogFile="nlog.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace"` on the `nlog` element. Maybe you will see something in the internal log file... Is the `NLog.config` in the bin directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dumb mistake.  I had not set the config file to copy to the output directory.

Comment: I am sure this is a noob question - how do I get Visual Studio to automatically copy NLog.config to the output folder when building?

Comment: @WebUser: Select the file in the Solution Explorer and then make sure that the 'Build Action' is set to 'Content' and the 'Copy to Output Directory' is set to something other than 'Do not copy'

Comment: @DilbertDave Hey I am using VS2015 and there is not such option when i go to properties

Comment: @flexxxit: I can still see the option in VS2015 - select the file and in the 'Properties' panel you should see the 'Build Action'. If you can't see the Properties then right-click on the file in the Solution Explorer and click "Properties". HTH

Answer (score 4):

Web User, find your NLog.config in uour files list in Solution Explorer. Right click NLog.config and choose properties. choose "Copy always" at "Copy to output directory" and be happy ^)